# Is there some npm packages writing by es6 style?

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

I want try to write some npm lib with es6 style, but can't find some online npm package for help. Is it the time to write es6 style package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out https://babeljs.io/.

Install

```
$ npm install --global babel
```

Usage

```
$ babel script.js
```

You can try [online](https://babeljs.io/repl/) too.